# How can I make IntelliJ default to a Jest configuration?

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs, create-react-app

I have Create React App applications that I test with Jest. I've been using VSCode, but am now switching to IntelliJ. I'm wanting to duplicate the test run/debug behavior that I get in VSCode.

In VSCode, whenever I run or debug, in VSCode, a prompt comes up in the terminal asking which file, test, etc, that I would like to run. See first photo below. As of right now, I can run the tests in IntelliJ, but it doesn't ask me which tests I want to run.

Also, in IntelliJ, if I run a test file by itself, or a single test by itself, it seems to make a new configuration automatically, which I don't like.

I'd like to have just a single configuration for Jest and have any/all tests default to that configuration if possible.

Behavior in VSCode, that I'd like in inteliiJ

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is no way to do this - a run configuration is auto-created once you run test from a gutter/context menu. I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with having multiple configs, provided that you can always use the gutter icons to run preferred tests. anyway, to see the prompt similar to what you have in VSCode, you can simply run Jest in terminal with `jest` - the output you can see comes from Jest itself, not from the IDE

Comment: The problem is that IntelliJ is smart enough to figure out that it's a jest test. But it automatically sets the Jest package to react-scripts. I need it to be react-app-rewired

Comment: you can specify `react-app-rewired` as a **Jest package:** in Jest run configuration [template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/changing-default-run-debug-configurations.html) - all new configurations in this project will have this package chosen by default

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That works, thanks. I misunderstood how templates were used.